# Bash data - how to subtract 30 minutes

Tags: bash, date, date-formatting

I have read many documentation on this subject, but I have not found the correct solution to my problem.

I would subtract 30 minutes from a certain variable.
I have prepared it roughly like this:

```
Monday=0120 
date_mon=`date -d $Monday +"%H%M"`
echo $date_mon
0120
new_date_mon=`date -d "$date_mon -30 min" +"%H%M"`
date: invalid date '0120 -30 min'

edit: on the Linux is fine:
0050
```

(the hour must be in such form %H%M).

I do not know what I'm doing wrong.

**$Edit:**

The above code is correct. I tried to execute it by MobaXterm where the error is displayed, but as I did it directly on Linux it works.

Comment: The input date `Monday` is in `HH:MM` format? i.e. `01:20`

Comment: what does `0120` mean?

Comment: Monday is in HHMM format. I need it without colon. I have to deduct from 0120 30 minutes to get the result 0050.

Comment: What version of `date` are you using? Your code works as expected using `date` from GNU coreutils 8.27.

Comment: Chepner, You're right, this code works. I tried to launch it using MobaXterm and it does not work there. But as I checked by Jenkins on Linux, everything works fine. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

following command subtract 30min to next Monday 01:20

```
date -d 'Monday 0120 -30min' +'%F %T'
```

otherwise using arithmetic operations

```
hhmm=0120
((m_from_start_day=(10#$hhmm)/100*60+(10#$hhmm)%100))
((m_from_start_day-=30))
((hhmm=m_from_start_day/60*100+m_from_start_day%60))
echo $hhmm
```

To keep the zeros

```
printf -v hhmm  %04d $((m_from_start_day/60*100+m_from_start_day%60))
echo $hhmm
```

Note the commands were fixed because leading 0 indicates the input is octal `(10#$hhmm)` must be used instead of `hhmm`

Also printf -v hhmm, works except if hhmm is declared with `-i`, (`declare +i hhmm` to remove flag) otherwise leading zeros will convert from octal to decimal.

Comment: The first option continues to display the same error, but second is ok, but maybe you know how to keep two zeros before 50? I need 0050 value.